# Colocar "0" delante de cantidades numéricas dentro de una string a las cuales les falte una cifra numérica siguiendo el contexto de un patrón regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, str-replace, replace

```py
import re

input_text = '2000_-_9_-_01 8:1 am'  #example 1
input_text = '(2000_-_1_-_01) 18:1 pm'  #example 2
input_text = '(20000_-_12_-_1) (1:1 am)'  #example 3


identificate_hours = r"(?:a\s*las|a\s*la|)\s*(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)"

date_format_00 = r"(\d*)_-_(\d{1,2})_-_(\d{1,2})"
identification_re_0 = r"(?:\(|)\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*(?:\)|)\s*(?:a\s*las|a\s*la|)\s*(?:\(|)\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*(?:\)|)"

input_text = re.sub(identification_re_0,
                    #lambda m: print(m[2]),
                    lambda m: (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_{m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

Estaba intentando estandarizar datos de fecha-hora que ingresen los usuarios en lenguaje natural para que luego puedan ser procesados.

De modo que una vez obtenidas las fechas en este formato, necesitaba que aquellos valores numéricos de **meses**, **días**, **horas** y/o **minutos** que hayan quedado con una sola cifra se estandaricen a 2 cifras, colocando un `"0"` delante de ellos para compensar la posible cifra faltante.

De modo que en el output las fecha-hora queden expresadas de este modo:

`YYYY_-_MM_-_DD(hh:mm am or pm)`

```
'(2000_-_09_-_01(08:01 am))'   #for example 1
'(2000_-_01_-_01(18:01 pm))'   #for example 2
'(20000_-_12_-_01(18:01 am))'  #for example 3
```

He utilizado la función `re.sub()` porque contempla la posibilidad de que dentro de la misma `input_text` haya mas de una ocasión en donde deba realizar un reemplazo de este tipo. Por ejemplo en un input en donde `'2000_-_9_-_01 8:1 am 2000_-_9_-_01 8:1 am'`, debería realizar 2 veces este procedimiento ya que hay 2 fechas presentes (o sea hay 2 veces en donde aparece este patrón)

Comment: ¿Y no sería mejor hacer las validaciones y/o conversiones durante la introducción de los datos, en vez de intentar usar una regex mágica que se ajuste a todas las posibilidades que quieres capturar?

Comment: De momento estaba intentando armarlo asi, en parte ya esta semi estandariazado al ya ajustar de nombre de mes a numero, y dejarlos ordenados al modo que sale en la pregunta, lo ultimo que queda es completar ceros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quizas esto te sirva. Utiliza `parse` con `fuzzy=True`. Este método intentará "adivinar" y convertir a datetime el texto que le pases. Una vez en datetime le puedes dar el formato que desees mediante `strftime`

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse('2000_-_9_-_01 8:1 am', fuzzy=True)
print(dt)
2023-09-01 08:01:00

text = dt.strftime("(%Y_-_%M_-_%D(%I:%M %p))")
print(text)
'(2023_-_01_-_09 (08:01 AM))'
```

Comment: Gracias, no conocía la existencia de ese método, por ahora lo utilizare de forma temporal hasta armar una buena regex que ponga los `"0"` . Sin embargo creo que seria muy útil agregar este code en una linea al final de todo el algoritmo de estandarización para terminar de asegurarme que el texto quede maso menos ordenado para usarse con `datetime`, y luego usar los `replace()` necesarios, por ejemplo con los `/` o los `-` pasarlos a `_-_` que es lo que yo uso para diferenciarlo del signo `-` de las restas